# Как убрать отступ только с одной стороны контейнера в bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Кто-нибудь знает как убрать отступ только с Одной стороны контейнера в bootstrap ? Пробовал fluid на он убирает на ширину на весь контейнер.

[image: картинка]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте

```
.container {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.container {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6"><img src="//placehold.it/900x300/c69/f9c/?text=First" class="img-responsive" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6"><img src="//placehold.it/900x300/9c6/cf9/?text=Second" class="img-responsive" alt=""></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужно убрать отступ у одного конкретного контейнера, то добавьте ему дополнительный класс, например, `marginleft`:

```
<div class="container marginleft"></div>
```

А в CSS добавьте стиль для него:

```
 .marginleft {
     margin-left : 0px;
 }
```